# Program crashes on deleting array of pointers in struct

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Crashes when the delete command comes around. It's supposed make a struct with pointers to arrays, fill them with random numbers, and then deallocate the memory. Works fine until the delete command, in which it crashes with our without the for loop or boolean check.

```
int main() {

    cout << "start" << endl;
    //Creating Struct
    struct 
    {
        int* ptrarray[10];
        bool boolarray[10];
    } data;

    //Initializing Random Generator
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    cout << "Initializing: ";

    //Allocating Memory and generating random numbers with for loops

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {   
        int counter = 0; //Counts numbers set   
        cout <<  i << " "; //Counting arrays initialized    
        data.ptrarray[i] = new int [12582912]; // Memory Allocation 

        for (int j = 0; j < 12582912; j++)//Number Generating
        {
            *data.ptrarray[i] = rand() % 899 + 100;
            data.ptrarray[i]++;
            counter++;
        }

        //Checking for failed initializations and declaring if success
        if (counter == 12582912)
        {
            data.boolarray[i] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            data.boolarray[i] = false;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    //This is where it always crashes.
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if (data.boolarray[i] == true)
            delete[] data.ptrarray[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using MS Visual studio 2010.

Comment: This formatting is terrible. Please reformat and paste in gist.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is this line:

```
data.ptrarray[i]++;
```

You are changing the pointer, then using `delete []` on the modified pointer. This will not work: you must use `delete[]` with the exact same pointer you got from `new[]`.

Try

```
data.ptrarray[i][j] = rand() % 899 + 100;
```

instead so you don't have to change your pointer.

Comment: Even though it's a bit slower. Unless the compiler optimizes that away.

Comment: Most modern compilers are smart enough to recognize an array-filling loop `for(x=0; x<n; x++) arr[x] = f(x);` and will create an appropriate temporary variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot (and to everyone who saw the mistake). Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Well, okay. It deletes fine now. (I deleted data.ptrarray[i]++; and replaced *data.ptrarray[i] = rand() % 899 + 100; with data.ptrarray[i][j] = rand() % 899 + 100;) But now it doesn't print the proper range of integers, instead some wild numbers (negative, 0, way over 1000). Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, forget that, I had to change the print function in my extended code as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies with:

```
data.ptrarray[i]++;
```

This is modifying the pointer. When you then attempt to free that modified pointer, it crashes.

You can solve this by using a copy of the pointer to run through the array, or by indexing with the`j` variable as well:

```
data.ptrarray[i][j]
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.ptrarray[i]++;` is the problem.

You're incrementing your reference to the data, but then not resetting it to the start before trying to delete it.